# Requery Datasheet in Subform from Main form

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I am using Access 2013.

I am coding a requery on a datasheet inside a subform.

My setup:

- Using a navigation form with top and side buttons.
- Main active form is (Main_Hub)
- When Task tab is active the subform is (Task_List)
- On that subform are 3 datasheet forms (Task_Form_Priority_1_High) etc...

This is when the issue starts

- After adding a new task the datasheet form (Task_Form_Priority_1_High) does not update unless I click on the Task button (either the main task tab button or the side tab button)

I know I need to use something with `Forms!subform!form.requery`.

Here is an image of the form:
[image]

Edit:
(Main_Hub) has navigation button that has target (Task_List).
Task_List form contains 1 button to add task and 3 Datasheet forms (Task_Form_Priority_1_High), med, and low.
Those datasheet use queries as there record source (Task_Query_Priority_1_High), med, low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim down through all the forms in the following way:

```
Forms!Main_Hub!Task_List.Form!Task_Form_Priority_1_High.Form.Requery
```

The general syntax is:

```
Forms!MainForm!SubFormControlName1.Form!SubformControlName2.Form
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried to add your code to the Close button when adding a new task (And also a test button on the main page) But i get error 2465 "can't find the field 'Task_List' referred..."

Comment: Are you sure the subform _control name_, not the _form name_ is Task_List? Also, if you're using a navigation control, you need to specify that.

Comment: How do I check the control name?

Comment: You click on the control, open up the property sheet, and check the name property

Comment: The datasheet name is "Task_List". I do have a textbox named "Task_Title" and tried using that instead but same thing. The datasheets record source is: Task_Query_Priority_1_High. I free like something simple is just flying over my head here... I don't no why I am struggling so much

Comment: Start by supplying the right information. Your question states the subform is named Task_List, and that that subform contains 2 datasheet forms. I can't help you if your answer contains wrong information.

Comment: Yes it does, (Main_Hub) has navigation button that has target (Task_List). Task_List form contains 1 button to add task and 3 Datasheet forms (Task_Form_Priority_1_High), med, and low. Those datasheet use queries as there record source (Task_Query_Priority_1_High), med, low.

Comment: Figured out issue. Because Task_List is called from a Nav button it is place on a NavigationSubForm control. code works when that is switched.